# Need to a grep a file for specific word and count the occurrence for every hour

Tags: shell

I have a log file as below:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017:22:59:49 -0500] "GET /file/name/keyword HTTP/1.0" 200 59 1
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017:22:59:53 -0500] "GET /file/name/keyword HTTP/1.0" 200 59 2
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017:22:59:54 -0500] "GET /file/name/keyword HTTP/1.0" 200 59 1
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017:22:59:58 -0500] "GET /file/name/keyword HTTP/1.0" 200 59 0
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017:22:59:59 -0500] "GET /file/name/keyword HTTP/1.0" 200 59 1
```

I want to grep the log for a certain keyword and get the count every hour.

Need to take the current time and subtract with 1 to get the previous hour and the count of occurrence in it to be mailed via shell script

Comment: cat file name | grep keyword | uniq -c | wc -l, and this didn't help me

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve], showing us a representative sample of your input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uniq -c` just do `prefix lines by the number of occurrences`, it means the lines should be exactly the same. You can use `sed` to make your line only have time info like `DD/MMM/YYYY:HH` then use `uniq -c` to count it.

I've use your sample data and adjust last 2 lines to different hour, then use this command and got a result as below. The prefix number `3` and `2` are the count of every hour.

`cat test.log | grep keyword | sed 's/.*\[\(.*[0-9]\{4\}:[0-9]\{2\}\).*\].*/\1/g' | uniq -c 
      3 09/Mar/2017:22
      2 09/Mar/2017:23`

If you just want last hour's count, try this:

`cat test.log | grep keyword | grep $(date --date="@$(($(date +%s) - 3600))" "+%d/%b/%Y:%H") | wc -l`

First use `date +%s` translate current time to seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, then minus 3600 seconds and set the result back to `date` to format it, and `grep` the date and count lines.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used the SED and it worked out and in the same output in need to eliminate the current hour and display the results for previous hours.